# how to test if button click fired then it update the state or not?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-testing-library

//People Card

```
const PeopleCard: React.FC<PeopleListProps> = ({ peoples }) => {
    const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState<number>(8);
    const [btnHide, setBtnHide] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const showMoreHandler: React.MouseEventHandler<
        HTMLButtonElement
    > = (): void => {
        setShowMore((prevState) => prevState + 8);
        if (showMore === 16) {
            setBtnHide(true);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <PeopleCards data-testid='ples'>
                {peoples.slice(0, showMore).map((people) => (
                    <PeopleList data-testid='people' key={people.login.uuid}>
                        <Avatar src={people.picture.large} alt='people' />
                        <PeopleWrapper>
                            <Title>Name: </Title>
                            <PeopleTitle data-testid='name' changeColor={people.name.title}>
                                {people.name.title.length > 4
                                    ? people.name.title.slice(0, 4)
                                    : people.name.title}
                                . {people.name.first} {people.name.last}
                            </PeopleTitle>
                        </PeopleWrapper>
                        <PeopleDetails>
                            <Title>Email: </Title> {people.email}
                        </PeopleDetails>
                        <PeopleDetails>
                            <Title>City: </Title> {people.location.city}
                        </PeopleDetails>
                    </PeopleList>
                ))}
            </PeopleCards>
            <ShowMoreBtn
                onClickHandler={showMoreHandler}
                hide={btnHide}
                label='show more'
            />
        </>
    );
};

export default PeopleCard;
```

//People card.test.tsx

```
it('should change state', async () => {
    const setStateMock = jest.fn();
    const useStateMock: any = (useState: any) => [useState, setStateMock];
    jest.spyOn(React, 'useState').mockImplementation(useStateMock);
    render(<PeopleCard peoples={peoples} />);
    // const cardEle = screen.getAllByTestId('people');
    const btnElement = screen.getByRole('button');
    expect(btnElement).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.click(btnElement);
    expect(setStateMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(16);
});
```

Here I tried to test if button click event fired then it will update the state or not? but I can not get it. I have two state in people card components and after show more button clicked it should update the shorMore state into 16. How to achieve that? could you please guys help me?

Comment: you can ```console.log``` your ```showMore``` or ```btnHide``` inside your ```showMoreHandler``` function and see if it is fired or not

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test that the state has changed, then you should just expect it to be called, regardless of the arguments:

```js
//...
expect(setStateMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

To test the actual behavior besides the state change, I would go with something like the following

```js
it('should show 16 people after clicking on "Show more"', async () => {
    //Arrange
    const { getByRole } = render(<PeopleCard peoples={peoples} />)
    const btnElement = getByRole('button')

    //Act
    fireEvent.click(btnElement)

    //Assert
    expect(screen.getByTestId('ples').children.length).toEqual(16)
});
```

I'm not 100% sure if you should check for `.children` or `.childNodes` length, but you get the idea.